# DataFormatString not working for money

Tags: c#, html, format

I have a gridview in this grid i have a column Valor (Money).

```
<asp:BoundField
    HeaderText="Valor"
    DataField="Skfbt"
    sortExpression = "Skfbt ASC"
    DataFormatString="{0:#,#0.00}"
    ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center"
    HeaderStyle-CssClass="TabelasHeader branca-10NN"
/>
```

I'm trying to use DataFormatString to make a value that is 25789,90 to 25.789,90 but using DataFormatString="{0:#,#0.00}" it's not working,someone know what i'm missing?

Comment: I think it's DataFormatString, not DateFormatString :)

Comment: "it's not working" is never a good explanation for what's happening. What result do you get at the moment?

Comment: I tried using "{0:C2}" as sugest,but got the same values,like (-5229,17  / 1283,99    /    14267,85)

Comment: Vinicius, what's the dataType you are trying to format to currency ?

Comment: Its Real(Brazilian money),i already tried DataFormatString="{0:#,0.00}" to.

Answer (score 0):

Try `DataFormatString = "{0:C2}"`

Comment: Didin't work,the values stay the same (-5229,17 for example)

Answer (score 0):

In a forum I saw someone with the same problem, and the solution that worked was addind the `HtmlEncode="False"` to the TAG and it worked.

So, your code would be like that:

```
<asp:BoundField
HeaderText="Valor"
DataField="Skfbt"
sortExpression = "Skfbt ASC"
DataFormatString="{0:c}"
ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center"
HeaderStyle-CssClass="TabelasHeader branca-10NN"
HtmlEncode="False" />
```

following the link for the source: [Link](https://forums.asp.net/t/936393.aspx?format%20currency%20in%20gridview%20boundfield)